# Time.deltaTime does not appear to be working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The following function is supposed to move the object it is attached to gradually until the object reaches its target position. Unfortunately, the object just snaps to the position instead. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

```
public void moveToPosition()
{
    Vector3 target = new Vector3(26.2f, 25.8f, -36.2f);
    while(Mathf.Abs(target.magnitude - transform.position.magnitude) > 0.5f)
    {
        //While not at target position,
        Vector3 unitPosVec = (target - transform.position).normalized;
        transform.position += unitPosVec * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

I have tried making the target position a lot farther and it still snapped to the position. Additionally, I tried multiplying the added distance by .001 and it still instantly jumped. By using Debug logs, I can tell that the object moves over the course of hundreds of frames, but only the final position is shown. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have a question: why is it in a loop?

Answer (score 2):

I'd say [`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) is proven to be working pretty well - in thousand of applications. It returns

> The interval in seconds from the last frame to the current one.

This is rather a case of "you're holding it wrong". Your entire `while` loop will be executed within a single frame.

=> You might want to convert this into a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)

```
public void moveToPosition()
{
    StartCoroutine(MoveToPositionRoutine());
}

private IEnumerator MoveToPositionRoutine()
{
    Vector3 target = new Vector3(26.2f, 25.8f, -36.2f);
    while(Vector3.Distance(target - transform.position) > 0.5f)
    {
        //While not at target position,
        Vector3 unitPosVec = (target - transform.position).normalized;
        transform.position += unitPosVec * Time.deltaTime;

        // in a Coroutine this tells Unity to "pause" the routine here
        // render the current frame and continue from here
        // in the next frame
        yield return null;
    }

    // to ensure to end with clean values
    transform.position = target;
}
```

Way easier would be however to use [`Vector3.MoveTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html) which avoids any overshooting and then rather use [`Vector3 ==` operator](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_eq.html) which uses an approximated equality with a precision of `1e-5`

```
public void moveToPosition()
{
    StartCoroutine(MoveToPositionRoutine());
}

private IEnumerator MoveToPositionRoutine()
{
    var target = new Vector3(26.2f, 25.8f, -36.2f);
    while(transform.position != target)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target, Time.deltaTime);

        yield return null;
    }

    transform.position = target;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

delete the while loop inside the method and put the call to moveToPosition() in fixedUpdate()

something like this:

```
Vector3 target = new Vector3(26.2f, 25.8f, -36.2f);

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if(Mathf.Abs(target.magnitude - transform.position.magnitude) > 0.5f)
    {
        moveToPosition()
    }
}

  
public void moveToPosition()
{            
    Vector3 unitPosVec = (target - transform.position).normalized;
    transform.position += unitPosVec * Time.deltaTime;        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Vector3.MoveTowards function with the Time.deltaTime value to achieve gradual movement:

```
    public float speed = 5.0f; // Adjust the speed as needed
    
    public void moveToPosition()
    {
        Vector3 target = new Vector3(26.2f, 25.8f, -36.2f);
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

This modification allows you to move the object towards the target position.Try this if it could works for you :)